# Pivoting a data with Nvarchar and Float/integers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data(below) that i am trying to get a pivot out summing the quantity and aggregating the columns with a desired result as shown below. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
Location1 Location2  Product Mode Customer Quantity
61          151       A     TL    Bill     800
61          151       A     TL    Bill     800
61          501       B     TL    Nan      800
61          501       C     TL    Cas      800
61          901       B     TL    Cas      800
61          901       B     TL    Cas      800
61          111       C     TL    Bill     800
```

Desired Result:

```
Location1 Location2  Product Mode Customer Quantity** 
61          151       A     TL    Bill     1600
61          501       B     TL    Nan      800
61          501       C     TL    Cas      800
61          501       C     TL    Cas      1600
61          111       C     TL    Bill     800
```

Comment: Please don't post images for data and desired results.  Take the time to write out table structure and sample data so that the people trying to help you have something to start with.  We aren't a free code-writing service, so provide some examples of what you've tried to do to solve the problem.  The more effort you put into your post, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Comment: What happened to '901' in your desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm a little bored, i'll do your work for you.

```
Declare @data as Table(Location1 int, Location2 int, Product varchar(1), Mode varchar(2), Customer varchar(5), Quantity float)
Insert into @data(Location1, Location2, Product, Mode, Customer, Quantity)
Values
(61, 151, 'A', 'TL', 'Bill',800 )
, (61, 151, 'A', 'TL', 'Bill',800 )
, (61, 501, 'B', 'TL', 'Nan',800  )
, (61, 501, 'C', 'TL', 'Cas',800  )
, (61, 901, 'B', 'TL', 'Cas',800  )
, (61, 901, 'B', 'TL', 'Cas',800  )
, (61, 111, 'C', 'TL', 'Bill', 800)


SELECT
    Location1, Location2, Product, Mode, Customer, Sum(Quantity) as TotalQty
FROM
    @Data
GROUP BY
    Location1, Location2, Product, Mode, Customer
ORDER BY
    Product
```

And the Results:

```
(7 row(s) affected)
Location1   Location2   Product Mode Customer TotalQty
----------- ----------- ------- ---- -------- -----------
61          151         A       TL   Bill     1600
61          501         B       TL   Nan      800
61          901         B       TL   Cas      1600
61          111         C       TL   Bill     800
61          501         C       TL   Cas      800

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: That won't aggregate the columns respective to the tons. I tried that already. Does it matter that the quantity is a float?

Comment: No, Float doesn't matter at all.  Also, pivot really isn't needed to achieve your desired results -- please see above.  This is a simple grouping.